# Finding the minimum of a column and adding a new column by a group

Tags: r, data.table

I need to find and add a column with value '1':

- For each group value of variable `z_axis`, the row with the minimum `x_axis` (if there is a tie, the one with minimum `y_axis`)
- For each group value of variable `z_axis`, the row with the minimum `y_axis` (if there is a tie, the one with minimum `x_axis`)

So for the following `DT`,

```
set.seed(2)
library(data.table)
test_surfaces<-data.table(
  x_axis=c(sample(1:10,20,replace = T)),
  y_axis=c(sample(1:10,20,replace = T)),
  z_axis=c(sample(1:3,20,replace=T)),
  avail=c(sample(0:1,20,replace=T))
)
```

I tried

```
test_surfaces[,.SD[which(y_axis==min(y_axis))][1,candidate:=1],by=z_axis]
test_surfaces[,.SD[which(x_axis==min(x_axis))][1,candidate:=1],by=z_axis]
```

which gives output

```
   z_axis x_axis y_axis avail cand
1:      3      2      2     0    1
2:      3      6      2     0   NA
3:      3      1      2     1   NA
4:      1      6      1     0    1
5:      2      9      4     0    1
```

which is ok for finding the minimum by group. But

1. It does not compare `x_axises` and select the one with minimum `y_axis` (i.e. it should select row 3, instead of row 1 for `z_axis=3`
2. Data table is not modified permanently (i.e. column 'cand' is not permanenet). For this, i know I can use `join()`, but it's not elegant.

Comment: So you add a column for x_axis and then y_axis?

Comment: Not really. I m using mike s suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to sort by `x_axis` and `y_axis` and then simply assign the first value to be 1 for each group. This will place the lowest `x_axis`/`y_axis` combination first for each group.

```
test_surfaces[order(z, x_axis, y_axis), 
              candidate:=rep(c(1,0), times = c(1, .N - 1)), by = z]
test_surfaces[order(z, y_axis, x_axis), candidate:=c(1, candidate[-1]), by = z]

head(test_surfaces[order(z, x_axis, y_axis)])
#   x_axis y_axis z avail candidate
#1:      2      2 1     0         1
#2:      3      2 1     0         0
#3:      5      6 1     0         0
#4:      6      1 1     0         1
#5:      6      9 1     1         0
#6:      8      4 1     1         0
```